# How to explain the single threaded nature of JavaScript using an analogy?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have read many articles about JavaScript single-threaded, asynchronous nature and wanted once and for all to find a real-world analogy that could be used to explain it.

I envisage JavaScript being like a Cafeteria Hall. You have a series of people coming into the cafeteria hall through the main doors. As with most Cafeteria's, you have a tray system - whereby a person will pick a tray, place it on the rails and visit each food station until they reach the till. Now if you imagine that each person hits the rail one after another - this is the single threaded nature of JavaScript. However, as JavaScript also can execute asynchronously, then we need to apply this to the analogy...

So, lets say that in this food hall there are 5 food stations along the rail and we concentrate on three people hitting the beginning of the rail, Person A (synch), Person B (async) and Person C (synch). Person A, B and C go through food station 1 and get to food station 2 still in the same order. Now, Person A goes through food station 2 with no issues, however, Person B wants something that has run out and the chef's are currently cooking it. So, Person B (being async) is able to wait there until the meal is ready. Meanwhile, Person C gets their item and leapfrogs Person B. Person A and C now continue along the rail, whilst Person B continues to wait for their meal to be prepared. Finally, Person B collects their meal and they reach the till in the order A-C-B.

Hopefully, this illustrates how JavaScript uses a single thread (the rail) and how the order of returned data can be different at the end of execution when we have asynchronous bits of code being executed.

Does this analogy reporesent the nature of single-threaded, async JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can explain it a bit like the system McDonalds uses here in germany. If your burger is not available and it takes more than a few seconds to get it you get a number and take what you already have. When your burger is done someone comes around and gives you your burger. In a sense this is a callback that gives you the data you requested and now you can do your job (munch away on the burger)

Comment: Just thought about it again. Maybe you should add that the server has to wait till you munched your burger and give him the paper wrap back so that he can go around and serve the next customer^^

Comment: Isn't this more related to Promises?